# Testing equality of mean vectors

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean

Which is the best method to test equality of mean vectors say that of age, height, weight and BMI of 150 men and women?

Comment: It depends on your data. If they are reasonable Normal distributed then you must use the T-test, otherwise you can use the non parametric test of kolmogorow smirnov for small samples or the wilcoxon-mann-whitney for large samples (as your data are)

Comment: Isin't Hotelling's T2 test used in such contexts?